# What am I doing wrong in this lint error suppression attempt? And is there a better way?

Tags: c++, lint, pc-lint

I have the following line of code:

```
ftDCB.ByteSize = FT_BITS_8;
```

And lint (PC-lint via Visual Lint, specifically) gives me a message 1924 on it ("C-style cast -- More Effective C++ #2").

FT_BITS_8 is #defined in a third party header file, and there's where the cast is:

```
#define FT_BITS_8           (UCHAR) 8
```

And UCHAR is a typedef from another third party header file:

```
typedef unsigned char UCHAR;
```

The thing it's being assigned to (ftDCB.ByteSize) is a BYTE, which is also a typedef for an unsigned char:

```
typedef unsigned char       BYTE;
```

I don't really want to modify the third-party headers, so I tried to suppress the message in my code:

```
//lint -e(1924) C-style cast
ftDCB.ByteSize = FT_BITS_8;
```

But I get the same 1924 message.

What am I doing wrong here? And is there a cleaner way to do what I want to accomplish (other than modifying the third-party header)?

Comment: what about `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: I don't want to modify the third-party header file, which is where the actual cast seems to be coming from.

Comment: If the lint warning comes from a third-party header, and you don't want to modify that third-party header, then you just have to live with the warning.

Comment: Are you sure that that's true, Emmet? I've used what I think to be this same tactic on other such warnings from other third party libraries.

Comment: That macro definition isn't even correct; it should be `#define FT_BITS_8 ((UCHAR) 8)`. Evaluating `sizeof FT_BITS_8` should yield `1`; with the existing definition, `sizeof FT_BITS_8` is a syntax error. In most cases it won't matter, but it's sloppy coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, answering my own question, the following seems to work:

```
ftDCB.ByteSize = /*lint -e(1924) C-style cast */ FT_BITS_8;
```

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue, and I found a nicer way to fix this (remember code readability is a main aspect of code quality and if it gets littered with lint comments, it's quite ugly).

So if you are provided with a header you cannot change (like peripheral definitions in microcontrollers), you should include them in a way, so that PC-lint knows it's a library header. There are several ways, the easiest is probably to use angle brackets.

So instead of:

```
#include "peripheral.h"
```

Use:

```
#include <peripheral.h>
```

This will tell PC-lint to treat the file as library header, which gives you access to finer control over messages using `-elib` and it's brothers.

If your messages are based on a macro, the `-elibmacro` provides a nice possibility:

```
//lint -save
//lint -elibmacro(1924)
#include <peripheral.h>
//lint +elibmacro(1924)
//lint -restore
```

This will block message 1924 coming from all macros defined in `peripheral.h` and includes from there.

The `-save` and `-restore` are probably superfluous, but it's a habit of mine as I got into trouble often enough with disabling to much at one point and not getting any messages any more.

Note, that all headers included in `peripheral.h` will be treated as library headers now, but you usually want that.

You may want to read the PC-lint manual chapter 6 concerning libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As FT_BITS_8 is a macro, the `-esym(1924,FT_BITS_8)` in your std.lnt file would also remove all instances of this issue.